# Switch to light-mode

Tags: settings

I'm using Cinnamon 5.2.7 desktop. I started once with Ubuntu then I came back on Cinnamon and all was set dark-mode (Nautilus, LibreOffice, Calculator, etc.). How can I go back to light-mode??? I've checked in settings/Appearance but I can only change the backgroud of my Desktop. I've also tried installing https://www.linuxedo.com/2021/10/dark-mode-in-cinnamon-desktop.html without any success. Any clue? Command lines? Menu path???
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes but even with dark mode off it remains dark

Comment: Nothing is set.

Comment: Window border theme, window control theme, Desktop theme, Icon theme, Change desktop background. When I change any, it change Desktop and menu but not background of Nautilus and all the rest

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; Cinnamon is a desktop and not an OS.  Please provide OS/release details.

Comment: I've added screenshot. I've been able to come back to a nicer display with the selected applet light-mode selection (Dopple, Ambiance, Menta and Humanity) but Nautilus, Calculator and top menu are still black.

Comment: OS: Ubuntu Cinnamon 22.04.1 LTS x86_

Comment: Most likely, Nautilus, Calculator are using GTK4, and the cinnamon menu cannot apply theme on them. Use GNOME's appearance settings to change their theme.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *Ubuntu Cinnamon is a remix and not a flavor*

Comment: I finally reinstall ubuntu 22 with cinnamon on top. Thanks for your help anyway